# Apply Ito formula with integral functions

Tags: stochastic-processes, stochastic-calculus, finance

I have an issue trying to apply Ito's Formula on a specific dynamics.
Basically I have the following dynamics:

$df(t,T) = \frac{1}{2}\partial_T(\sigma^2(t,T))dt + \partial_T(\sigma(t,T))dW(t)$

Where $W(t)$ is a Winer process.

What I'm looking for is the dynamics of:

$B(t,T) = e^{-\int_t^T f(t,s)ds }$

I tryed to apply Ito's formula but I cannot write $B(t,T)$ as $h(t,T,f(t,T))$ because of the integral function at the exponent.

Is there any way to find such an $h$ so that I can apply Ito's formula?

In case of negative answer, how can I derive the the dynamics of $B(t,T)$ w.r.t. $t$? (i.e. the Ito differential $dB(t;T)$ )

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let us first compute the dynamic of $\int_t^Tf(t,s)ds$:
\begin{align}
d\left(\int_t^Tf(t,s)ds\right) &= -f(t,t)dt + \int_t^Tdf(t,s)ds \\
&=  -f(t,t)dt + \int_t^T \left(\frac{1}{2}\partial_T(\sigma^2(t,s))dt + \partial_T(\sigma(t,s))dW(t) \right)ds \\
&= -f(t,t)dt + \alpha(t,T)dt + \Gamma(t,T)dW(t)
\end{align}
Now applying Ito to the function $\phi(x) = \exp(-x)$ with the process $\int_t^Tf(t,s)ds$, we have :
\begin{align}
dB(t,T) = B(t,T)\left[\left(f(t,t)-\alpha(t,T) + \frac12\Gamma(t,T)^2\right)dt - \Gamma(t,T)dW(t)\right]
\end{align}

Comment: Thanks for the answer. However I cannot understand the meaning of $\int_t^T \frac{1}{2}\partial_T(\sigma^2(t,s))dt\ ds$ and, as well, of $\int_t^T \partial_T(\sigma(t,s))dW(t) \ ds$. What does it mean to integrate an Ito differential w.r.t. another variable? 
I would like to get an explicit expression. So to get it I'd like to apply something like Fubini's Theorem in order to use the foundamental theorem of calculus (I mean, I'm talking just heuristically). Is it possible to do something like that?

Comment: Yes. So the first integral is a double integral w.r.t the Lebesgue measure. I used (standard) Fubini theorem to switch the integrals. For the second integral, I used Fubini stochastic.

Answer (score 0):

You have the form:

$f(X) = e^{-X}$

\begin{align}
  df(X) & = \frac{\partial f}{\partial X}dX + \frac{1}{2} \frac{\partial^2 f}{\partial X^2} (dX)^2 \\
   & = -fdX + \frac{1}{2}f(dX)^2 \\
\end{align}

Substitute $dX = df(t,T)$ as given at begin then you obtain the result

Comment: Unfortunately it's not in the form $e^{-X}$, there's an integral function at the exponent that makes stuff harder